# crossdomain.xml file for Silverlight POST

Tags: silverlight, crossdomain.xml

Okay  I'm doing a simple post like

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers["content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(ResultServerAddress, UriKind.Absolute), "POST", "data=" + "stuff");
```

When I deploy this to dev, and look at the post in fiddler, I see a 404 error with the address of the page I'm posting to looking for crossdomain.xml. Is there no way I can tell my code to not look for this file? Or does every site that wants to revieve posts from mine have to have a crossdomain.xml file in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to post to sites that do not want you to do that. 
Unless your application is hosted within the same domain or your application is trusted and you use Silverlight 5.

Read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx for more information.